# "You should not use <Link> outside a <Router>" Issue in Nested Routes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I've seen a similar question, but I unfortunately still have a bug in my code that I cannot seem to solve :(

My `react-router-dom` version is 5.2.0, and my `react` version 17.0.2.

I'm in the process of building a more complex React app, but I'm also able to replicate the bug with the simple code below. I've basically stripped everything out of the application except a `<Test />` component.

Here's my `App.js` file, where I'm employing React-Router and have a single route for `'/test'`. At that route, I'm rendering my `<Test />` component, then also using React-Router's `<Link />` component. **This works perfectly fine!** Code below for both my `App.js` and `Test.js` files is below.

#### App.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import Test from './components/Test';

const App = () => (
    <Router>
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path='/test'>
                <Test />
                <Link to='/' className='text-white'>
                    Go back home
                </Link>
            </Route>
        </Switch>
    </Router>
);

export default App;
```

#### Test.js

```
import React from 'react';

const Test = () => {
    return (
        <>
            <h1 className='text-white'>Hello, world</h1>
        </>
    );
};

export default Test;
```

**My bug occurs when I try to bring `Link` from `react-router-dom` into my `<Test />` component.** For example, I'm trying to do this:

#### Test.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const Test = () => {
    return (
        <>
            <h1 className='text-white'>Hello, world</h1>
            <Link to='/' className='text-white'>
                Go back home
            </Link> 
        </>
    );
};

export default Test;
```

But whenever I visit `/test` (i.e. `http://localhost:3000/test`), my application breaks and I see "Error: Invariant failed: You should not use Link outside a Router." Screenshot below:

[image]

I thought I had found an [answer here](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/6789#issuecomment-502490351), but I don't understand what it means to import or export from my bundle.

Any and all help is greatly appreciated! This has been a huge roadblock in my application as I'm trying to use React-Router's `<Link />` component inside of other components rendered within the `<Switch />`.

Answer (score 0):

**Try to put this in the Route prop render:**

```js
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import Test from './components/Test';

const App = () => (
   <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route
          exact
          path="/test"
          render={() => ( // look at this
            <>
              <Test />
              <Link to="/" className="text-white">
                Go back home
              </Link>
            </>
          )}
        />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
);

export default App;
```

Comment: Thank you @messias ! See my own answer to the question for how I was able to solve 

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the bug by just deleting my `node_modules` directory and then re-installing all of the required packages with `npm install`! The nested `<Link />` component now works as expected.